# C# determining object type of list item

Tags: c#

I'm trying to do a project for my C# class that adds students from either Student object(parent) or DormStudent(child) into a List that is set up for Student objects. I need to read in an object based on student ID and determine if its a student or dorm student and fill out the rest of the form accordingly.

```
    int pos = MainMenu.myList.FindIndex(x => x.ID == validID);
    if (MainMenu.myList[pos] == Student)
    {
        Student tempStu = MainMenu.myList[pos];
        nameTextBox.Text = tempStu.Name;
    }
    else
    {
        DormStudent tempDorm = MainMenu.myList[pos];
        dormCheckBox.Checked = true;
        dormTextBox.Text = tempDorm.Dorm;
        if (tempDorm.MealType == "B")
        {
            basicRadioButton.Checked = true;
        }
        else if (tempDorm.MealType == "M")
        {
            mediumRadioButton.Checked = true;
        }
        else
        {
            highRadioButton.Checked = true;
        }
    }
```

here is the list and object items

```
    public static List<Student> myList = new List<Student>();

    [Serializable]
    public class DormStudent : Student
    {
        public string Dorm{get; set;}
        public string MealType { get; set; }
        public DormStudent() : base()
        {
            Dorm = "No Dorm";
            MealType = "B";
        }
        public DormStudent(int i, string n, string d, string m) : base(i, n)
        {
            Dorm = d;
            MealType = m;
        }
    }

    [Serializable]
    public class Student
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<int> Grades;
        public Student()
        {
            ID = 0;
            Name = "No Student";
            Grades = new List<int>();
        }
        public Student(int i, string n)
        {
            ID = i;
            Name = n;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since DormStudend is derived from student, you need to ask whether the object is a DormStudent first. (The usual from specific to general approach)

So you need to swap your If-Statement like this:

```
if(MainMenu.myList[pos] is DormStudent)
{
  ...
}
else
{
   ...
}
```

Reply to your comment:
You can use the as keyword instead to make it abit easier. 
as is basically a 'try cast' It will return the casted object or null if it cannot cast.

```
Student student = MainMenu.myList[pos];
DormStudent dormStudent = student as DormStudent;

if(dormStudent!= null)
{
     dormTextBox.Text = dormStudent.Dorm;
}
else
{
    nameTextBox.Text = student.Name;
}
```

Comment: how about converting the list item to a DormStudent object? error saying i can't convert type

Comment: omg thank you, it's finally working now just like i want it to.

Answer (score 1):

To determine if an object is of a particular type, use the [is](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw.aspx) operator.

ie.

```
if (MainMenu.myList[pos] is Student)
{
    ...
}
else if (MainMenu.myList[pos] is DormStudent)
{
    ...
}
```

Now, in this particular case that won't work since the way I wrote code above will catch both types in the first clause since `DormStudent` inherits from `Student`.

To handle this, reverse the checks:

```
if (MainMenu.myList[pos] is DormStudent)
{
    ...
}
else if (MainMenu.myList[pos] is Student)
{
    ...
}
```

This still has the problem that if any other type that inherits from `DormStudent` or `Student`comes along it will be caught by the above if-statements. If you don't want that, here's how to only identify the known types:

```
if (MainMenu.myList[pos].GetType() == typeof(DormStudent))
{
    ...
}
else if (MainMenu.myList[pos].GetType() == typeof(Student))
{
    ...
}
else
{
    ... // other type?
}
```

Comment: This will not work since DormStudent is derived from student.

Comment: but won't it always say student whether a DormStudent was put in that spot or not?

Answer (score 1):

I leave the comments on whether this design is optimal to others, but what you're looking for is the `is` operator keyword.

```
var someStudent = MainMenu.myList[pos];
//Check for null here
if (someStudent is DormStudent )
{
    DormStudent tempDorm = someStudent as DormStudent ;
    dormCheckBox.Checked = true;
    dormTextBox.Text = tempDorm.Dorm;
    if (tempDorm.MealType == "B")
    {
        basicRadioButton.Checked = true;
    }
    else if (tempDorm.MealType == "M")
    {
        mediumRadioButton.Checked = true;
    }
    else
    {
        highRadioButton.Checked = true;
    }
    Student tempStu = someStudent ;
    nameTextBox.Text = tempStu.Name;
}
else
{
    nameTextBox.Text = someStudent.Name;
}
```

But you can also you `as` with a null check:

```
var someStudent = MainMenu.myList[pos];
//Null check here?
var dormStudent = someStudent as DormStudent;
if (dormStudent != null)
{
    DormStudent tempDorm = someStudent as DormStudent ;
    dormCheckBox.Checked = true;
    dormTextBox.Text = dormStudent.Dorm;
    if (dormStudent.MealType == "B")
    {
        basicRadioButton.Checked = true;
    }
    else if (dormStudent.MealType == "M")
    {
        mediumRadioButton.Checked = true;
    }
    else
    {
        highRadioButton.Checked = true;
    }
}
nameTextBox.Text = someStudent.Name;
```

Answer (score 1):

if (!(MainMenu.myList[pos] is DormStudent))

you need **is** operator to test the type and test for descendant. You can as well retrive Student from the list and cast it to DormStudent using **as** operator and check if null.